# Is there a need in Neo4j to have initial scripts just like rdbms store needs initial CREATE(and other DDL scripts) scripts to insert,update etc?

Tags: spring, neo4j, liquibase

I recently was working with `liquibase` which is capable of generating the initial `DDL` script for my `JPA entities`.

I am trying to do the same for my entities which has `Neo4j` as the store. Is there any library like `liquibase` which I can use to get my work done. Can someone put light on this ?

**Is there a need in Neo4j to have initial scripts just like rdbms store needs initial `CREATE`(and other `DDL` scripts) scripts to insert,update etc ?**

I don't want to use the auto capability of spring boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need in Neo4j to create or update schema itself, as you're doing in SQL. Schema is dynamically builds from the data you have in your database.

But if you're trying to manage migration of the data stored in your database, you can take a look at [liquigraph](https://www.liquigraph.org/latest/index.html). It's able to manage a CYPHER queries within changesets.

Comment: Suppose my JPA entity has an attribute with @Index ( unique = true)  property. Shouldn't I generate the CYPHER for it?

Comment: Yes, in this case you should generate a CYPHER and put it into changesets. Spring is also able to manage indexes. To keep one guy responsible for that, don't forget to check `indexes.auto` property of your Spring configuration (by default it is `none`).

Comment: Many thanks for this. I was looking into generating CYPHER scripts for index and constraints manually through liquigraph using java api's. If there is any doc regarding the usage of liquigraph through java please update me.

Comment: I'm aware only about [official documentation](https://www.liquigraph.org/latest/index.html#detailed_section), there is a section **Java API**. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Ok Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is there any way to run the liquigraph in offline mode ? please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56254443/how-to-generate-index-and-constraint-script-for-neo4j-store-using-liquigraph-in