# How to generate Index and Constraint script for Neo4j store using Liquigraph in java?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, liquigraph

I am trying to generate the `Index` and `Constraint` for my spring entities. I am not using any capability of spring-data to do it such as `indexes.auto=assert`.

How can I generate the scripts with following conditions

1. I need to generate scripts in `offline` mode. ie I cannot provide any `Neo4j` 
   server,user,password etc.
2. I need to use the java api to achieve it. I am able to create liquigraph change-log but I can't find a way to generate the script.

The maven dependency I have used is

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.liquigraph/liquigraph-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquigraph</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquigraph-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

3. My output should be a file containing the scripts like these

   `CREATE CONSTRAINT ON ( action:Action ) ASSERT action.id IS UNIQUE`

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you will run your changeset from Java, you don't need to put any credentials into it, just CYPHER queries.

Create **changelog.xml** and put in resources.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<changelog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.liquigraph.org/schema/1.0/liquigraph.xsd">
  <changeset id="action-contraint" author="JITHIN">
    <query>CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (action:Action) ASSERT action.id IS UNIQUE</query>
  </changeset>
</changelog>
```

Then you can run migration from **Java**, and all credentials you can keep in your application.

```java
Configuration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .withMasterChangelogLocation("changelog.xml")
        .withUri("jdbc:neo4j:http://localhost:7474")
        .withUsername(user)
        .withPassword(pass)
        .withRunMode()
        .build();

Liquigraph liquigraph = new Liquigraph();
liquigraph.runMigrations(configuration);
```

After execution your constraint should be added, at least works for me

```
╒══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"description"                                                         │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│"CONSTRAINT ON ( __liquigraphlock:__LiquigraphLock ) ASSERT __liquigra│
│phlock.name IS UNIQUE"                                                │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"CONSTRAINT ON ( action:Action ) ASSERT action.id IS UNIQUE"          │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: I have my changeLog as a java object and I don't have an neo4j server to connect to.

Comment: Where do you want to apply a changeset?

Comment: I don't want to apply, I just want it to be generated in a file.

Comment: Ok, got it now. Not sure it is possible, liquigraph should have some datasource to check what was applied, what wasn't, and apply (migrate) only delta. If you want to generate every time CYPHER file with all changes (because you have no datasource to compare with), then no migration needed, and liquigraph as well, you can just put every script in file by yourself. 
Not sure about your case, but seems like current liquigraph functionality is not able to solve it. If you need both: liquigraph migration and generated CYPHER file, the you can implement custom converter and parse XML.